# Why backup sql server query is not working without variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

it is working......

```
declare @dbName varchar(50)
set @dbName='myDb'
    BACKUP DATABASE @dbName TO DISK = 'c:\backup\myDb.bak'
```

But
Why is it not working? where as both are similar query.

```
 BACKUP DATABASE 'mydb' TO DISK = 'c:\backup\myDb.bak'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) says:

```
BACKUP DATABASE { database_name | @database_name_var } 
    TO <backup_device> [ ,...n ]
```

So it takes a database name (f.e. `mydb`) or a variable (f.e. `@dbname`.)  But not a string literal (f.e. `'mydb'`.)

Just omit the quotes to change the string literal to a database name:

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydb TO DISK = 'c:\backup\myDb.bak'
```